# Team Foundation Sever: allowing any user to run `tf get $/Project`

Tags: tfs, build-process

My objective is to allow any developer to log into our build server with their Windows credentials, and run a shared script that would:

1. Get the latest code from TFS
2. Build the project with msbuild
3. Deploy the project with msdeploy

Is this a viable approach to consistent deployments?

I'm stuck at step one, because `tf.exe get $/Project` needs to have a workspace defined. Each developer would need to define their own workspace in their own folder, from what I understand, because multiple workspaces cannot point to the same working folder.

Comment: You could always create the workspace as "Shared" `tf vc workspace /new /permission:Public`

Comment: If you want consistency, why not use a build automation tool? Either the one built in to TFS or something like Jenkins or TeamCity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use a Public workspace, which can be used by any valid users.

When you create a workspace, you can specify the options of workspace permission:

- **Private**: Only the owners can use, check in files to, or administer the workspace.
- **Public Limited**: Any valid user can use the workspace. However, only
  the owners can check in files to or administer the workspace.
- **Public**: Any valid user can use, check in files to, or administer the
  workspace.

You can either create a workspace [in VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/create-work-workspaces) or [with command line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workspace-command).